# Optimization (scipy.optimize) L-BFGS-B wrapper args treating array elements as one variable

Tags: optimization, parameters, scipy, wrapper

I am unable to understand the source of this error:

line 327, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
TypeError: SSVOptionPriceObjFunc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'marketVolSurface'

The relevant code is below:

```
x0 = [1.0, 0.0] # (lambda0, rho)
x0 = np.asarray(x0)
args = (spot, 0.01*r, daysInYear, mktPrices, volSurface)
# constraints: lambd0 >0, -1<= rho <=1
boundsHere = ((0, None), (-1, 1))
res = minimize(SSVOptionPriceObjFunc, x0, args, method='L-BFGS-B', jac=None, 
bounds=boundsHere,options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
```

The function to be minimized is below. The first two arguments are the free variables, while the other five are fixed as parameters.

```
def SSVOptionPriceObjFunc(lambda0, rho, spot, spotInterestRate, daysInYear, marketPrices, 
marketVolSurface):
```

My intention is to find (lambd0, rho) giving a minimum. From the debugger, it seems that my initial guess x0 is interpreted as a single variable, not as a vector, giving the error about a missing positional argument. I have tried passing x0 as a list, tuple, and ndarray; all fail. Can someone spot an error, or suggest a workaround? Thank you in advance.

Update: I have found a solution: use a wrapper function from the functools package to set the parameters. 
    import functools as ft
    SSVOptionPriceObjFuncWrapper = ft.partial(SSVOptionPriceObjFunc, spot=spot, 
    spotInterestRate=0.01 * r, daysInYear=daysInYear, marketPrices=mktPrices,
    marketVolSurface=volSurface)

Then pass SSVOptionPriceObjFuncWrapper to the minimizer with args = None

Thank you for the replies.

Comment: (Without trying): I think `lambda0` in your function will be passed a 1d-array of size 2. That's probably not what you expect. Try changing your function to: `def SSVOptionPriceObjFunc(x, spot, spotInterestRate, daysInYear, marketPrices, marketVolSurface)` plus inside `lambda0, rho = x` Also see the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), which actually imply that behaviour: `fun(x, *args) -> float`

Comment: The first argument to the objective function is the `x0`, the iteration variable.  The rest get values from the `args` parameter, and are fixed.  You have to some how combine `lambda0` and `rho` into one array.

Answer (score 0):

Take the documented `minimize` inputs seriously.  It's your job to write the function to fit what `minimize` does, not the other way around.

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args=(), 
    fun: callable
    The objective function to be minimized.

    fun(x, *args) -> float

    where x is an 1-D array with shape (n,) and args is a tuple of the fixed 
    parameters needed to completely specify the function.
```